# Logging Steps in Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I want to add logging to methods that I have in page objects in Selenide(written in Java).

The elements are defined first in each class like so:

```
public SelenideElement reviewEditRiskResultButton = $(byText("Review/edit Risk Results"));
```

Used later in methods below:

```
public CaseManagement reviewRiskAssessment() {
    // if the risk case has already been locked and the review risk button is available, click and continue
    if(reviewEditRiskResultButton.exists()){
        highlight(reviewEditRiskResultButton).shouldBe(visible).click();
        return this;
    }
    //if the risk case has been locked for the first time, click on the more options button first
    else {
        highlight(moreOptionsButton).shouldBe(visible, Duration.ofSeconds(50)).click();
        sleep(5000);
        highlight(reviewEditRiskResultButton).shouldBe(visible).click();
    }
    return this;
}
```

Is there a way to have a generic logic for each method that will log name of the Selenide element wrapped by highlight(), the name of the page, the name of the method and which line the code is on?

The second question is if it will be possible to cast logging up one level. The tests are executed through ReadyAPI, which has its own logging where the GUI test step name is included, but would it be possible to include logs from Selenide there as well?